# widget который меняет размер при нажатий

Tags: flutter, виджет

Как сделать widget, который меняет размер (изначально widget показывает оглавление после нажатия показывает оглавление + содержание ) и желательно со свойством scrollable?

Comment: Сами что пытались сделать? Покажите код.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример виджета **AnimatedContainer** из [офф доки](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html), там же по ссылке можно прямо в браузере запустить и посмотреть как работает.

```
/// Flutter code sample for AnimatedContainer

// The following example (depicted above) transitions an AnimatedContainer
// between two states. It adjusts the `height`, `width`, `color`, and
// [alignment] properties when tapped.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selected = !selected;
        });
      },
      child: Center(
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          width: selected ? 200.0 : 100.0,
          height: selected ? 100.0 : 200.0,
          color: selected ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
          alignment:
              selected ? Alignment.center : AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          child: FlutterLogo(size: 75),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```